# heroku createsuperuser does not create a user. Does not make entry in auth_user table

Tags: django, heroku

```
    (cfehome) C:\Dev\cfehome\verojewels>heroku run python manage.py 
    createsuperuser
    Running python manage.py createsuperuser on ⬢ verojewels... up, run.7672 
    (Free)
    Username (leave blank to use 'u48267'): shruti
    Email address: shruti.karva@gmail.com
    Password:
    Password (again):
    Superuser created successfully.
```

after this also, no entry in auth_user table is made

Answer (score 0):

Execute following command to initialize database.

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

Also don't forged to add `Heroku Addon` for database and correctly configure your Django project in `settings.py`.
If you are using Postgres, please check if you have something like following and `DATABASES['default']` is not overridden.

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()
```